@types/node is two major versions behind Node.js
My project-located @types/node (20.14.8) is two major versions behind Node itself (22.3). Node is managed by Homebrew, and @types/node by pnpm. TypeScript 5.5 is installed globally. I think @types/node is the types of Node's API, and is used by tsc to check types and by editor code assist tooling to aid coding, so the versions ought to be aligned. But I'm not certain that's true.
I don't believe I experience an actual coding or execution problem, so this is really an intellectual curiosity. Internet search doesn't reveal a lot about this.

The @types/node package follows the current LTS of nodejs, which is 20.15.0 currently. It lags a bit behind because types do not change in every nodejs release.

Thanks, @TimsibAdnap -- understood, and I see the sense in that. Thanks for those edits, Jon.

@types/node follows the Node.js long-term support (LTS) build. h/t to Timsib Adnap @TimsibAdnap for the answer.
